# Python - open file in paint with whitespaces

Tags: python, image, paint

I am trying to open an image in paint with python, however, the path contains a space, paint throws an error saying it cannot find the path because it has just split the string until the first space.
Can someone tell me how to solve this without changing the path?
Here is my code:

```
import subprocess, os

paintImage = "C:\\Users\\Me\MY Images\\image.png"

#get the path of paint:
paintPath = os.path.splitdrive(os.path.expanduser("~"))[0]+r"\WINDOWS\system32\mspaint.exe"
#open the file with paint
subprocess.Popen("%s %s" % (paintPath, paintImage))
```

However, paint opens and says that C:\Users\Me\MY contains an invalid path, because it has not counted the space. I have tried replacing the space with %20, but that does not work.

Thanks

Comment: Does `subprocess.Popen([paintPath, paintImage])` help?

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much!!! It works.

Comment: I'm not intending to write this up into a full answer (so anyone else go ahead...) but glad to have a happy customer ;-) Really the fact that passing a string without also using `shell=True` can be used **at all** (although not with filenames containing space) is just some weird quirk of Windows.

Comment: Thanks, I was having trouble with that - I am actually creating a bigger program which requires you to be able to draw on an image, but I didn't want to have to write an image editing program in python.

Comment: Generally unless you actually need to use any kind of shell interpretation of the command line, it is better to use a list with `subprocess.Popen`

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the following line

```
paintImage = "C:\\Users\\Me\MY Images\\image.png"
```

to

```
paintImage = "C:\\Users\\Me\MYImages\\image.png"
```

`MYImages` should be the new name of the folder no spaces.